# Full-text indexing an archived file

Tags: zip, sql-server-express, ifilter

Greetings,
in short, I have to find out whether I can implement a way to index zipped .rtf files via IFilter under Sql Server 2008 Express for fulltext search.

Long version:
this question is mostly a theoretical one - I'm neither experienced nor knowledgeable enough to find out whether such a thing is possible on my own.

The problem is as follows. There's a limited-size Sql Server Express 2008 R2 database thats going to store large .rtf files, probably 2-10k of them, and index them for fulltext search. Now, they probably wont fit into the 10gb limitation, thus I'm wondering if they could be archived (zipped, for instance) and stored that way. Fulltext search should be doable on them, in their zipped state.

My thought was to try to chain ifilters in some way to achieve this (I've no idea if thats doable), or there could be a different solution that I'm not seeing atm; I'd appreciate any input, as I'm kinda at a loss.

Comment: i have the question about indexing zip files content as well, but you may check `FILESTREAM` feature.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You may have a much easier time using something like [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html).  You could extract the text for the files and index it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I'm afraid there isnt enough time to transition to Lucene for the current project. Unfortunately, it isnt about doing the right thing, but rather making do with what we got atm, and thats IFilters.